# How to set the correct Bean class path

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

#### Hello

I have this snipped of code:

```
<bean id="properties" class="org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent" >
    <property name="location" value="classpath:prj.properties"/>
</bean>
```

inside the file `../META-INF/spring/my-contexts/foo.xml` and I'm getting a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

All works fine the XML file is located here `../META-INF/spring/foo.xml`

So, how can I instantiate this bean from a XML files located in another folder than `../META-INF/spring/*`

#### Thanks!

#### Edit 1: added error output

```
karaf@root> Exception in thread "SpringOsgiExtenderThread-55" org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find cl
ass [classpath:org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent] for bean with name 'properties' defined in OSGi resource[classpath
:META-INF/spring/my-contexts/foo.xml|bnd.id=247|bnd.sym=my.foo.bundle]; nested exce
ption is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: classpath:org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent not found from bundle [my.foo.bundle]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.j
ava:575)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1330)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:896)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:566
)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:89
5)
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$1600(AbstractDelegatedExecutionAppli
cationContext.java:69)
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$4.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplication
Context.java:355)
        at org.springframework.osgi.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.completeRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionA
pplicationContext.java:320)
        at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor$CompleteRefreshTask.ru
n(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:132)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Please include more details about the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a missing import in your Manifest.MF file.

You are using an osgi application server with a bundle, this means, your classpath is set up by the information inside of MANIFEST.MF

To fix this issue, you have to add an entry inside of your Manifest: 
    Import-Package: org.apache.camel.component.properties

Which tool are you using to generate your Manifest?

If you use maven-bundle-plugin in your pom.xml, add an import-package tag.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
      <instructions>
        <Import-Package>
        *,
            org.apache.camel.component.properties
        </Import-Package>
      </instructions>
     </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Also, take at look into the [maven-bundle-plugin documentation](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html)

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thanks for the answer. I'm using Maven for compiling and generating a jar file.